# Android. Как динамически добавить блоки с информацией при старте Activity

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске Activity, загружались блоки с информацией по определенному шаблону (количество их неизвестно заранее)
Прикрепляю пример того, что нужно сделать.[пример](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJLnb.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере происходит скорее всего следующее:
в методе `Activity` `onCreate()` создается `RecyclerView` - он олицетворяет список.
Данные для заполнения списка приходят с сервера при помощи `HTTP GET` запроса.
Затем все эти данные парсятся из `JSON` в объекты класса "Новость" и затем массив этих "Новостей" передается в `Adapter` для `RecyclerView`

Собственно создание самого View для отрисовки данных и взаимодействия с ними - читайте о `RecyclerView`
А для того, чтобы заполнять список с сервера гуглите такие слова `REST GET requests`, `Volley`, `Retrofit`